# Are wireless mice still a no-no for gaming?

Tags: mouse

I remember when I tried a wireless mouse years back and it was horrible. It did not feel responsive enough in games. Should I consider buying a wireless mouse if it otherwise seems good?

Comment: I think you'll find that this is a subjective question. Many people swear even now that the latency or accuracy of a wireless mouse makes them insufficient for gaming. Others claim that they have absolutely no issues. In addition, a large factor of this would involve the quality of the hardware product. At that point, we're diving into providing shopping recommendations, which are also subjective.

Comment: Not to mention the type of game.  I wouldn't use a wireless mouse for an FPS, but I have no problems playing slowly-paced games with them.

Comment: Mmmm, [Nachos](http://xkcd.com/654/)

Comment: It depends on if it operates in the gigahertz range instead megahertz. And laser or optical. And hundreds of dollars instead of tens. All the former of which is what you want if you can afford it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had no issues with lag/responsiveness, but this is very hit or miss depending on the user (the same reason why some people use gaming CRTs).

The only downside I've had is that the batteries make the mouse a little heavier, which causes faster fatigue for long periods of gaming.

Also, you run the risk of batteries dying on you in the middle of a frag fest.

Answer (score 7):

Wireless mice can be fine for gaming if you spend enough. I purchased a Wireless Logitech G7 5 years ago and used it for competitive gaming with no problems. I never had interference, never lost connection (as far as I can remember) and its response was great. But I also paid for that. I think at the time I spent between 60 and 70 dollars on it.

Something you may want to ask yourself is: do I play games so competitively that it's not worth the risk of interference or loss of responsiveness? If you're competing or just fear the thought of that happening, then I'd get a wired mouse. Otherwise, spend a little more, do some research and you'll be fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You do indeed get what you pay for. And $200 gets you a Logitech V550 Nano Cordless Laser Mouse, [Review on Gigaom.com](https://gigaom.com/2008/10/14/logitech-v550-nano-cordless-laser-mouse/), that lasts 18 months on 2AA, on which the "tracking is excellent. All presumably thanks to the 2.4 GHz RF wireless technology which Logitech says provides an exceptionally robust signal that exchanges data 300 times faster than conventional 27 MHz wireless."

Comment: See also, [Why did trackballs disappear?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/why-did-trackballs-disappear) on Retrocomputing.SE for an extended discussion about a "freewheeling-track-nub" mouse (the Nano, in my answer and its comments)